# How would I setup a Sveltekit API enpoint that accept POST from other origin?

Tags: sveltekit

I want to use Sveltekit to accept a server-initiated POST from another origin ( not same origin).

According to the Sveltekit documentation at https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables, it says that "Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden".

CSRF protection can be entirely disabled in `svelte.config.js` but that seems like a bad idea since I only want one specific endpoint to be accessible.

Svelte answers with "Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden" if I `curl -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5173/path --data "{}"` for example.

What would be a feasible way to open up one endpoint within Svelte for this?

Comment: Wondering the same